# How to create compact unit displays in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, dynamic-island

I'm looking to create a compact display for a unit and value, maintaining Apple's design language. Is there a native way to do this in SwiftUI besides a simple `Text` element?

It should look like this demo image (from Apple):

[Dynamic Island unit display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYm8B.png)

I've tried approximating the look with a `Text` component, but it doesn't look quite right to me:

```swift
HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 2.0) {
    Text("1:23")
        .font(...)
    Text("H") // unit display
        .font(.caption2)
        .fontWeight(.semibold)
}
```